# How to add "New Terminal Tab at Folder" to Favorite?

Tags: finder, big-sur

In Big Sur's Finder: When right clicking a directory there is a an option to open the directory in a New Terminal Tab:

[image]

There is not such an option for favorites:

[image]

If possible: What is simple procedure to add  a menu item to open the favorite location in a Terminal Tab at the Shortcut?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, though I wait to be proved wrong!